# GoLang: gocui border color

Tags: go

The AI bot is acting up so I'm asking here:

I have this code which just outputs two windows and instead of the **background**, I want the **border** to be green.

I've tried:

```
g.Highlight = true
```

per [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jroimartin/gocui#View.Highlight) that still doesn't work.

[image]

Here is my entire code:

```
package main

import (
    // "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/jroimartin/gocui"
)

func main() {
    // Create a new gocui view
    g, err := gocui.NewGui(gocui.OutputNormal)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }
    defer g.Close()

    g.SetManagerFunc(layout)

    if err := g.SetKeybinding("", 'q', gocui.ModNone, quit); err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }

    if err := g.SetKeybinding("", '1', gocui.ModNone, view1); err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }

    if err := g.SetKeybinding("", '2', gocui.ModNone, view2); err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }

    if err := g.MainLoop(); err != nil && err != gocui.ErrQuit {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }
}

func updateView(g *gocui.Gui, v *gocui.View) error {
    // Check if the view is active
    if v != nil && v == g.CurrentView() {
        // If the view is active, set its background color to yellow
        v.BgColor = gocui.ColorYellow
    } else {
        // If the view is not active, set its background color to default (nothing)
        v.BgColor = gocui.ColorDefault
    }

    return nil
}

func layout(g *gocui.Gui) error {
    // maxX, maxY := g.Size()

    g.Highlight = true

    // Create a new view with the name "myView"
    if v, err := g.SetView("view1", 0, 0, 20, 10); err != nil {
        if err != gocui.ErrUnknownView {
            log.Panicln(err)
        }

        // Set the default background color of the view to nothing
        v.BgColor = gocui.ColorDefault
        v.Title = "View 1"
        v.Wrap = false
        // fmt.Fprintln(v, "View 1")
    }

    // Set a second view with the name "myOtherView"
    if v, err := g.SetView("view2", 25, 0, 45, 10); err != nil {
        if err != gocui.ErrUnknownView {
            log.Panicln(err)
        }

        // Set the default background color of the view to nothing
        v.BgColor = gocui.ColorDefault
        v.Title = "View 2"
        v.Wrap = false
        // fmt.Fprintln(v, "View 2")
    }

    return nil
}

func view1(g *gocui.Gui, v *gocui.View) error {
    if _, err := g.SetCurrentView("view1"); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    updateHighlighting(g, v)

    return nil
}

func view2(g *gocui.Gui, v *gocui.View) error {
    if _, err := g.SetCurrentView("view2"); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    updateHighlighting(g, v)

    return nil
}

func updateHighlighting(g *gocui.Gui, v *gocui.View) error {

    current := g.CurrentView()

    for _, view := range g.Views() {
        if view == current {
            current.BgColor = gocui.ColorGreen
        } else {
            view.BgColor = gocui.ColorDefault
        }
    }

    return nil
}

func quit(g *gocui.Gui, v *gocui.View) error {
    return gocui.ErrQuit
}
```

Comment: Yes, I linked the docs in my question that I referenced and I posted my entire code above

Comment: My bad, thanks for supplying both.  I think I figured out a solution for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `View`'s frame is handled by the `Gui` that renders that frame.  You have your `Gui`'s highlight set to true already, but you don't set `SelBgColor` or `SelFgColor`.

From https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jroimartin/gocui#Gui:

```
    // SelBgColor and SelFgColor allow to configure the background and
    // foreground colors of the frame of the current view.
    SelBgColor, SelFgColor Attribute

    // If Highlight is true, Sel{Bg,Fg}Colors will be used to draw the
    // frame of the current view.
    Highlight bool
```

By changing the beginning of your layout to the following, adding `g.SelFgColor = gocui.ColorGreen`:

```
func layout(g *gocui.Gui) error {
    // maxX, maxY := g.Size()

    g.Highlight = true
    g.SelFgColor = gocui.ColorGreen
    ...
    ...
```

Then you'll get a green border with black background:
[image: green border (with black background)]

If you don't want the background to be green also, take this line out:

> `current.BgColor = gocui.ColorGreen`

[image]

It's a little confusing at first because both `View` and `Gui` have `SelFgColor` `SelBgColor` and `Highlight`, but `View`'s attributes control the selected text in the view, not the border of the current view in the Gui.